# How to set parameters for SqlDataSource UpdateCommand

Tags: asp.net, gridview, parameters, sqldatasource, updatecommand

For a Gridview:

I am trying to use a stored procedure for the first time in a SQLDataSource for the UpdateCommand:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="TECT_DataSource" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:OracleConnectionString %>" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:OracleConnectionString.ProviderName %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT MPID, User_Id, Last_Name, First_Name
                   FROM Scripts.vw_Tect_Exam"
    UpdateCommand="P_TECT_UPD_EXAM_ID" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">  
    <UpdateParameters>                    
        <asp:Parameter Name="MPID" Type="Int32"  />  
        <asp:Parameter Name="User_Id" Type="String" />   
    </UpdateParameters> 
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I am wondering how the UpdateParameters get their values set, since I only specify a name?
The procedure `P_TECT_UPD_EXAM_ID` expects two parameters as input: `"in_MPID"` and `"in_UserId"`
I am also wondering how to map those values to the input parameters for the procedure as the names are different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set them something like this:

Example : In the example MPID is the sql parameter name @MPID

```
<UpdateParameters>                    
    <asp:ControlParameter Name="MPID" ControlID="MPID_TextBox" PropertyName="Text" />  
    <asp:ControlParameter Name="User_Id" ControlID="User_Id_TextBox" PropertyName="Text" />  
</UpdateParameters>
```

**Correction: Just spotted your proc param names so it must be**

```
<asp:ControlParameter Name="in_MPID" ...............
<asp:ControlParameter Name="in_User_Id" ...............
```

Comment: I am not sure what I should use for the ControlID since I am using a Gridview the textboxes only appear when I click the edit button and they get a different name generated for each row.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I really wouldn't use a `SqlDataSource`. It will be much easier if you make the call to the database in the code-behind (or a better yet in a Data Access Layer).

If you use a `SqlDataSource` the stored procedure call will only be available on that page. Every time you want to make that same call you will have to copy and paste the `SqlDataSource` or make a `UserControl` out of it.

The following example uses the Entity Framework to connect to the database and retrieve records:

```
public List<Record> GetAllRecordsByUserName(string credentials)
{
    List<Record> recordList;
    using (CustomEntities context = new CustomEntities())
    {

        IQueryable<Section> recordQuery = from records in context.Records
                                              where records.UserName == credentials
                                              select records; 
        recordList = recordQuery.ToList<Record>();
    }
    return recordList;
}
```